# Vee Validate validation too aggressive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I have a form where I use vee validate to validate it, the thing is, whenever I click on an input and then click somewhere else the error triggers, how can I make the error only to trigger after something has been typed in?

```
Form(@submit="handleSubmit" :validation-schema="schema" v-slot="{ errors }")
          .pb-2.pt-4
            Field#email.border-none.text-black.shadow-lg(type='email' as="input" name='email' placeholder='Email' v-model="email")
            span.text-red-500(v-if="errors.email") Email too short
```

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
      email: yup.string().required().min(3),
      nick: yup.string().required().min(4),
      password: yup.string().required().min(6),
    });
```

Comment: I think you could solve it by either using one of the available validation strategies, or write your own if they don't correspond to what you need. Both ways are described here: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/interaction-and-ux.html

Comment: @jkoestinger doesn't seem to work for vue 3

Comment: True, I guess you are using the v4 of vee-validate then. I never used it, but here is the equivalent for my previous link: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/validation#customizing-validation-triggers